# Laravel api Get method is working fine, Put,Delete,Post methods are not working with Angular, But all methods are working on localhost

Tags: angular, laravel, api

In localhost:8000 All methods are work with my Angular localhost:4200 
But After upload to server Only GET is working 
Please give me solutions

I already tried to add cores in middleware and linked in RouteMiddleware and api in kernel

api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::apiResource('/Author', 'AuthorController');

Route::get('/get/Author', 'AuthorController@getAuthors');

// Route::get('/get/Author', [
//     'uses' => 'AuthorController@index'
// ]);


Route::apiResource('/Article', 'ArticleController');
```

Middleware/Cors.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key');
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'apimw',
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'apimw' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

please fine me solution 
my error on Localhost:4200 from my angular is

[Console error on my angular(localhost:4200)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve1ae.png)

Comment: Your backend server is not running.

Comment: @varundhariyal but my get request is works fine

Comment: have you defined correct routes?, Tested services in postman?

Comment: my all routes are working fine on localhost:8000 But i upload my laravel to live server. after i can only work with get method other methods are not working

Comment: share your angular's service.ts code

Comment: <!-- `url = 'http://........com/backend'; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAuthors(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/get/Author`);
  }

  getAuthorsByPage(page:number){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/Author?page=${page + 1}`);
  }

  deleteAuthor(id){
    return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/api/Author/${id}`, {responseType: 'json'});
  } -->

Comment: id etc template variable may be going undefined, null.It may be the reason for http server error.

Comment: I think there no issue with angular, the issue is on laravel, the postman also giving the same error "Empty reply from the server" status code 0

Comment: your services are buggy! not laravel server

Comment: what can i do now?

Comment: Fix bugs and test service in postman.